# How to prune the returned sum to the precision that I want?

Tags: mysql

I use sql query to sum a cloumn in database :

```
SELECT SUM(sureness)  FROM tweet
```

But for some input it returns something like 8.8E-4 but I want it like 0.0008(exactly with 4 digits precision) . I searched the web but could not find a good example to understand.Is it possible to do that in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FORMAT` for defining that

```
SELECT FORMAT(SUM(sureness), 4) FROM tweet
```

Read more about in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/miscellaneous-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

`ceil` multiplied by the number of digits precision you need is the answer.

Then, simply re-divide it.

```
SELECT (ceil(SUM(sureness) * 10000))/10000 from tweet
```

Comment: Thanks but for number like '0.00140802456311524' it does not work and it returns 10000

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(ceil(SUM(sureness) * 10000))/10000`?